# Print spaces in between array values

Tags: java, arrays, project

I have this code,

```
else if (e.getSource() == saveButton) {
            Scanner scan;
            String es = " ";
            try {
                int status = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
                if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File newImageName = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(newImageName));
                    outFile.print(drawing.typefile);
                    outFile.print(drawing.iname);
                    outFile.print(drawing.width);
                    outFile.print(es);
                    outFile.print(drawing.height);
                    outFile.print(drawing.maxshade);
                    for(int r = 0; r < drawing.array.length; r++)
                        for(int c = 0; c < drawing.array[r].length; c++)
                            outFile.print(drawing.array[r][c]);


            //      outFile.print(drawing.paintComponent(newImageName));
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                }
             else if (status == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File could not be written, try again.");
                    //ex.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
```

and how do i get it to print spaces in between the values?
  it prints

```
P2image1.pgm320 275255132132130125125128
```

and i need it to print

```
P2image1.pgm320 275255132 132 130 125 125 128
```

hence there being a space in between each array value and i have tried a lot of stuff but i am thoroughly confused.

Thanks.

Comment: The simpler way is to put and outFile.print(" "); between each print statement.

Comment: `for(int c = 0; c < drawing.array[r].length; c++)
                            outFile.print(drawing.array[r][c]);`  Use `{ }` delimiters even for single line loops to make things less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print a space after each number, explicitly.

Have you tried something like:

```
for(int r = 0; r < drawing.array.length; r++) {
    for(int c = 0; c < drawing.array[r].length; c++) {
        outFile.print(drawing.array[r][c]);
        outFile.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the brackets, which I suspect were the important things missing when the OP 'tried a lot of stuff'.

Answer (score 0):

```
outFile.print(drawing.array[r][c]);
outFile.print(" ");
```

Comment: With the way the code is written, that would result in just one space at EOF.